# Image extraction work

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, background, automation, face-detection

Hope everyone is doing good and I really need some help with regards to automate the image extraction work.

We usually receive team/group images and the majority of the groups are shot on a natural background. We create the path and do the extraction on images.

The normal time of doing the extraction is around 30 minutes for 15-18 people, which we want to reduce.

Kindly suggest a way to automate or reduce time for such processing.

Thank you.

Comment: Hasn't this same exact question come up before and been deleted as spam or something?

Answer (score 2):

Use green screen & some fast isolation software, such as those from FXHome - the older [PhotoKey](https://fxhome.com/photokey-pro) or the new [Imerge](https://fxhome.com/imerge-pro) (which I haven't tried yet, but seems to also be half the price of the old one.)

Other solutions are available, but that's the one I've used the most. Googling for stills software isn't as easy as for movie, but it's out there somewhere. I recall trying out  [Greenscreen Wizard](https://www.greenscreenwizard.com) at some point, but I don't remember why I went with PhotoKey in the end.

Basically, either of these will let you use virtually a photo booth setup & swap the background for one of your choice in seconds, including killing colour-cast & spill.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply and for green screen we are already using a service. However, we receive all type of background and would be great if you could suggest something for the same.

Comment: I you want to be able to almost automate it, you need to be in control of the circumstances, otherwise it's back to doing it by hand.

Comment: Thanks and I can see most of the service provider provides extraction service for green background only and I would need for all the background. Is anybody know about any third party services.